# Problem in installing Google voice and video plugin for Gmail

Tags: rhel, software-installation, rpm, plugin

I just downloaded [Google talk plugin for voice and video](http://www.google.com/chat/video?hl=en) (for audio/video chat in gmail).

I am using RHEL6. I downloaded the plugin (64 bit, rpm format).

While installing it an error comes which says

[image]

and then installation stops. What is this? There is already newer version installed then why not it is installing ? What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Weird, it should work. How about this (a little bit) manual way:

1/ Add this contents to the file at `/etc/yum.repos.d/google-talkplugin.repo` (create the file if it doesn't exist, or check and maybe post its contents here)

```
[google-talkplugin]
name=google-talkplugin
baseurl=http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/rpm/stable/x86_64
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
```

2/ Install the plugin by running `yum install google-talkplugin`

I may have missed some parts in the middle (suspecting GPG keys or something -- please point out if you know it), but generally this is what the RPM does in the background.

Comment: Tried as you said, got the same error. 

Transaction Check Error:
  package libv4l-0.8.3-2.el6.x86_64 (which is newer than libv4l-0.6.3-2.el6.i686) is already installed

Comment: Then I suspect an error in the repo, particularly in the dependencies. You have a 64 bit installation so the package should not depend on *.i686. I suggest waiting for a while, refresh the repo and try again.

Comment: It is still .i686. Google hasn't updated it I guess.